# Вывод разных представлений в Yii2 в зависимости от значения поля в базе данных

Tags: yii2

В таблице `competition` (и в соответствующей ей модели `Competition`) есть поля  `id`, `name`, `status`. 
Во `views/index.php` стандартного CRUDа, созданного Gii, выводится список соревнований. Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на view/create/update в зависимости от поля `status` открывались разные виды в зависимости от типа соревнований - то есть для международных - один, для российских - второй и т. д. 
Скажите, как это реализовать в Yii2? В контроллере проверку поставить? (пока только это приходит в голову, но не очень понимаю как). Буду благодарен за развернутый ответ и за ссылки, где почитать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В контроллере получаете запись из БД и проверяете статус. Далее в зависимости от статуса рендерите нужное представление. Что здесь сложного?

Пример:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
  $model = Competition::findOne($id);
  ...
  switch($model->status) {
    case 1: return $this->render('_formfirst', ['model' => $model]);
    case 2: return $this->render('_formsecond', ['model' => $model]);
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это именно то, что мне нужно. Сложного ничего нет, мне главное понять как и запомнить. Очень помогли.